# Not able to connect connecting javafx components properly

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I was trying to connect javafx external components but getting this kind of error  " Unrecognised option :--module-pathD:\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib--add-modules=javafx.controls"
So what to do in order to remove this error

ack.imgur.com/RAjYw.jpg**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

As i also faced this problem i am assuming u are using Netbeans IDE

So after JavaFX becoming openjfx it has become a problem but it surely is advantageous, You just need to do a few extra steps

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction

but there is some problem here so in Project -> Properties -> Libraries

1. add javafx library to classpath in sources
2. add javafx library to modulepath in run

and under Project -> Properties -> Run

under vm options add (--add-modules javafx.controls, javafx.fxml)